# HISTCONTROL - When is erasedups executed?

Tags: bash

I know that `ignorespace` and `ignoredups` work in real time and prevent entries going into the buffer, **but when does `erasedups` come into play?**
Is it when the buffer is written/appended, is it when the shell is terminated, or is it when the exact command next gets run and it scours the history to remove all old instances?

I guess I'm asking, **when should I expect to see the effects of `erasedups` being set, and what else might impact the behaviour of the `erasedups` directive when it is set?**

For instance, does setting `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` change things within a shell session, compared to when `history -a` is not run?

For context, here's what is in use:

```
HISTCONTROL='ignorespace:ignoredups:erasedups'`
shopt -s histappend
shopt -s cmdhist
```

I'm still seeing duplicates in the history, even after I log out of SSH entirely and log back in. I can't decided if `erasedups` should have done it's work or not...or if the problem is/was because I had two terminals running?

Irrespective of the cause, I can't seem to get `erasedups` to take effect and clear out the history file a bit...

Comment: When you say _I'm still seeing duplicates in the history_, does that mean that you see duplicates in the output of `history` of when you examine the contents of `~/.bash_history`?

Comment: Both actually, duplicates in the file itself (they have a different record number for each one obviously, but the command itself is a duplicate) and the output of `history`

Comment: e.g. in the file `#1597544113$ vim ~/.bashrc$` and `#1597538286$ vim ~/.bashrc$`. Sorry about the formatting, but each of those is actually a two line entry. The `$` char is not in the file itself, it's denoting the EOL as I copied from the terminal display whilst using vim's `:set list` to see if there were space or something like that.